# How to implement WebRTC screen sharing in java webapp

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I have a requirement to implement a screen sharing feature in java web dynamic project by using WebRTC.I have googled it in last 3 days and have not get any dedicated article with java.Please anybody suggest or post me how to go over with WebRTC in dynamic java webapp